# NUnit set test name programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Having this unit test code snippet, taken from [NUnit TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9)

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("DivideCases")]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
    Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}

static object[] DivideCases =
{
    new object[] { 12, 3, 4 },
    new object[] { 12, 2, 6 },
    new object[] { 12, 4, 3 } 
};
```

It correctly runs the test three times, but in the output I get the same test method name, "DivideTest" run three times.

I would like to programmatically change/set the name of the test according to some values defined in the code.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the link that you posted, there is a snippet where you explicitly create the TestCaseData objects via a method linked via the TestCaseSource attribute. When you do this, you get control to set the name of each individual Test Case. See the last TestCaseData instance below.

```
 public static IEnumerable TestCases
  {
    get
    {
      yield return new TestCaseData( 12, 3 ).Returns( 4 );
      yield return new TestCaseData( 12, 2 ).Returns( 6 );
      yield return new TestCaseData( 12, 4 ).Returns( 3 );
      yield return new TestCaseData( 0, 0 )
        .Throws(typeof(DivideByZeroException))
        .SetName("DivideByZero")
        .SetDescription("An exception is expected");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is `TestCaseData` class and how this is run .I am not able to run same

Comment: Is there any way to do this when not using TestCaseSource?